# Easiest way to just get quotation marks to do what they should

Tags: punctuation

When I write "test" in latex (TeXStudio), I get this:

[image]

Clearly this is not what quotation marks should look like. There are a lot of answers on stackexchange about this question, but the ones I've seen seem pretty complex. **What is the easiest and quickest way to get them to look properly without me having to go through my entire document and change any quotation marks?**

ps. Why is this the default behaviour of quotation marks in Latex? It seems to me that nobody would ever want this.

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SE! You explained what you do not want. However, you may want to also explain what you want to achieve, i.e. how should these marks look like?

Comment: Load package  `csquotes` and use `\enquote{I am a wombat}` in your text.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/216166/37907

Comment: *Normal sane standards of quotation marks* ... you know that different languages are using different quotation marks?

Comment: @Johannes_B, but do any of them use the quotation marks as pictured above?

Comment: I don't know. But you input is simply wrong. Quotation marks in LaTeX are input a bit differently.

Comment: the input is a user error, it is like asking why latex does not produce the text 20% from input `20%`   the `"` should not be used, use `\`\`` and `''`

Answer (score 4):

As explained in the [*Not So Short Introduction to LaTeX2e*](https://tobi.oetiker.ch/lshort/lshort.pdf) by Tobias Oetiker, page 19, you should not use " for quotation marks. Use two ` for opening and two ' for closing.

[image]

This is implicit in the answer of @Andrew,  but I really do not see the need of making a command for that, instead of using it directly.

Answer (score 4):

Configure Texstudio to get the correct quotation marks. For example for German
quotations (http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/manual/current/usermanual_en.html#SECTION01):

[image]

Then the "-key will output the defined quotations:

```
 Input "quote" -> Output "`quote"'. in the editor window
```

Answer (score 3):

If you change the category code of the double quote character then you can define a macro that typesets `"test"` as ``test''. In doing this, the only downside that I can see is that you will run into problems if you forget a closing quote. It is also not unlikely that this will cause havoc with some packages -- for example, double quotes are used by [tikz](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz) so this will almost certainly not work if you want to use this in documents that also uses these features of `tikz`. You'd really be better off using the recommended quoting style of LaTeX, which is to use repeated left and right quotation marks instead of double quotes. A global search and replace in any decent editor that supports regular expressions should fix your current document.

For completeness I have added a `\quot` command to access the "real" double quote character and I have checked that accents like `\"a` still work as expected.

Here's the code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\quot{"}% allow access to the real double quote

\catcode`\"=13     % change the category code of "
\def"#1"{``#1''}   % and make "stuff" expand to ``stuff''

\begin{document}

  "test"

  Universit\"at

  You can also write \quot test\quot

\end{document}
```

and here is the output:

[image]

Comment: You shouldn't use \def. Your \def\quote destroys the quote environment.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks, I forgot about the `quote` environment. I've changed `\quote` to `\quot`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the csquotes package to make an " an outer quote. It will even adapt to conventions of different languages. But I personnally avoid to make ascii chars active, and have setup my editor so that it allows me to insert real quotes or \enquote with a shortcut.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\MakeOuterQuote{"}
\MakeAutoQuote{«}{»}

\begin{document}

  "test" 

  «text with some «inner quote»» 

  \enquote{text with some \enquote{inner quote}}

\end{document}
```

[image]