# how to generate correct single and double quotes in tex

Tags: xetex, pdftex, tex-core, texstudio

I am writing a tex document using book document class. I have already typed close to 100 pages, but i did a mistake with typing single and double quotes. 
I have done it as follows :
`"test double quotes"` and `'test double quotes'` which generated the output of the form : [image]

Is there a way i can generate the correct output without changing the quotes in all the places ? I saw some similar answers @ [Isn't there any other way of doing double quotes in LaTeX besides `` +  ''?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36812/isnt-there-any-other-way-of-doing-double-quotes-in-latex-besides) but none seemed to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a LuaLaTeX-based solution, which doesn't require you to modify the existing `"..."` and `'...'` pairs of quotes. It consists of a Lua function, called `msq` (short for 'make smart quotes'), and two utility LaTeX macros, called `\msqOn` and `\msqOff`, which activate resp. deactivate the Lua function. By "activating the Lua function", I mean assigning it to LuaTeX's `process_input_buffer` callback, where it acts as a preprocessor on the input stream.

[image]

---

*Addendum*, posted 1 March 2023: You should not use this answer to replace "dumb" with "smart" double-quotes if (a) your document uses `"` to denote hexadecimal numbers (e.g., `"FF=256`) and if you have two more more hex numbers in an input line, (b) if you use `"` in babel shorthand expressions, or (c) if you employ `"` to denote file names that include spaces; e.g., `xxx"aaa bbb"ccc.tex` to denote the filename `xxxaaa bbbccc.tex`. Please see [@DavidCarlisle's recent answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/676856/5001) for more information. Of course, if one of these issues arises just in a well-delimited part of your document, you could "protect" it from the action of the `msq` preprocessor by executing `\msqOff` at the start of the part in question (and, later on, executing `\msqOn` to restart the preprocessor action).

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[english]{babel} % or some other suitable language choice
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}

\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode}
-- msq: "make smart quotes"
function msq ( s ) 
  s = s:gsub ( '"(.-)"' , "\\enquote{%1}" )
  s = s:gsub ( "'(.-)'" , "`%1'" )
  return s
end
\end{luacode}

\newcommand{\msqOn}{\directlua{  luatexbase.add_to_callback( 
   "process_input_buffer", msq , "msq" )}}
\newcommand{\msqOff}{\directlua{ luatexbase.remove_from_callback( 
   "process_input_buffer", "msq" )}}

\begin{document}
\msqOn
"test double quotes" and 'test single quotes'


 "\,'Twas brillig and the slithy toves \ldots"

\medskip    
\msqOff
"test double quotes" and 'test single quotes'
\end{document}
```

Comment: What happens when you're quoting " 'Twas brillig and the slithy toves ..."?

Comment: @barbarabeeton - Actually, that case is handled just fine by my code. :-) I'll edit my MWE to demonstrate it.

Comment: @Mico : Thanks for your answer. I need to use xeLatex (as i am using fontspec pkg). And while compiling this, it needs luaLatex. Is there a way, i can compile this code with xeLatex as well ?

Comment: @mezda - The `fontspec` package works equally well under both LuaLaTeX and XeLaTeX. Using `fontspec` in no way precludes the use of LuaLaTeX.

Comment: @mezda - To answer the question in the second sentence: The code shown above absolutely requires LuaLaTeX. It will *not* work under XeLaTeX.

Comment: Actually, I didn't mean for the outside double quotes to be included.  What if this is in a British environment, and it begins with the apostrophe?

Comment: @barbarabeeton - I honestly have no idea if the OP uses British, i.e., single-quote, quotation marks. :-) Let's see if he/she speaks up and voices an opinion...

Comment: Oh, I'm just being difficult.  But that *is* a plausible scenario, so I'm suggesting that generality is a "good thing".

Answer (score 6):

Replace at first the last quote with the editor and  "Search and Replace"

```
"<space>  -> }
```

Then repcae the first quote with

```
" -> \enquote{
```

and then use always:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[french,ngerman,english]{babel}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}

\begin{document}

\enquote{quote} 
\enquote*{quote}

\enquote{quote \enquote{quote in quote}}

\foreignquote{ngerman}{quote}   
\foreignquote*{ngerman}{quote}

\foreignquote{ngerman}{quote \foreignquote{ngerman}{quote in quote}}

\foreignquote{french}{quote}    
\foreignquote*{french}{quote}

\foreignquote{french}{quote \foreignquote{ngerman}{quote in quote}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The OP asked whether "there [is] a way i can generate the correct output without changing the quotes in all the places?"

Comment: Your substitution rule, `"<space>  -> }`, doesn't catch the cases when the closing `"` character occurs at the very end of a line or is followed by a punctuation character.

Comment: The significant part of the question is that the user doesn't want to go and fix all their straight quotes `"` to the proper `“` (or `\`\`` in traditional TeX) and `”` (or `''` in traditional TeX), i.e. determine which straight quote should be changed to which.  Obviously, determining which ones should be `\enquote{` and which ones should be `}` is the same problem; so this isn't any simpler and doesn't answer anything. Sure, using enquote helps if using multiple languages and quotation styles, but the question mentions nothing about using multiple quotation-mark styles.

Answer (score 2):

You can set `"` and `'` as active characters and do appropriate definitions:

```
\catcode`\"=13 \def"{\bgroup \def"{”\egroup}“}
\catcode`\'=13 \def'{\bgroup \def'{\char`\'\egroup}`}

"test double quotes" and 'test double quotes'

\bye
```

Comment: Try this with French or Italian, where the apostrophe is part of grammar and orthography.