# Other than quotes and umlaut, does " mean anything special?

Tags: luatex, quotation

Using recent lualatex, fonts with TeX ligatures, but perhaps this question is more general...

I was just looking at @Mico code [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/499953/how-to-generate-correct-single-and-double-quotes-in-tex) regarding how straight double quotes are always replaced by right curly quotes, and how to fix user errors. Very nice.

In my case, I am trying to write a BASH script that pre-processes a *tex document, and looks for potential problems. I know how to write BASH, so that is not my question.

Among the various potential issues, my script will look for straight double quotes, and advise the user to substitute real curly quotes, or TeX ligatures, or whatever.

The macro `\"` can be used for umlaut. My question is: Other than quotes and umlaut, are there any other situations where straight double quotes might have a special TeX meaning?
Assume that the user is not writing math equations.

It seems that packages related to quotation processing, are not on this topic.

Comment: Not exactly a TeX usage, but it means something for filenames (`\input` etc.).

Comment: @JohnKormylo That is also very helpful.

Comment: Quotes appear frequently in Ti*k*Z code for node labels.

Comment: Thanks, @SandyG that is helpful to other users (I do not use TiKz).

Comment: General usage could enter the picture, though likely rare: (a) seconds of arc (latitude and longitude, and in astronomy); (b) inches (imperial measurements); (c) itself, in \ttfamily text, in style guides (e.g., episode title), in verbatim blocks, and in code listings (+ any coding language special meanings); (d) as (part of) the delimiter string for an expl3 sequence; (e) for some packages, inside CSV files. Plus also, in some transliteration and mapping schemes and in representational schemes in the linguistic sphere.

Comment: Question: would macros and expansion be part of the script? It's possible to have `\mydq` defined, for example. And, to prevent false positives, somehow ignore a package like `csquotes` handling whether `'` or `"` is used when `"` is typed.

Comment: The fact that you are using `bash` is almost certainly irrelevant to your question, and need not be mentioned, but `bash` is also almost certainly the *wrong* language for processing a TeX document (or any other data file).

Comment: @chepner Indeed, but I am not a programmer; bash is among the very few things I can handle, and it has the advantage that others know it. But bash is not irrelevant. Using a non-TeX language, I do not have to deal with catcodes or TeX-only special characters.

Comment: @Cicada Macros would not be part of the script. It is intended to trap common slef-caused user errors. For example, I do not use comments within the running text, but I might wish to use percent. The script will complain if it sees the % character, unless preceded by backslash. Although I know about TeX quotes, sometimes I type " out of force of habit. No problem with arc seconds, since I would directly use the Unicode character for that. And, I do not use monospace. But others might do that, so your comments are valuable.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`"` is part of the tex syntax for a number.  `"FF`  is hex FF ie 255.

It is also part of `web2c` based TeX implementation filename syntax.
`xxx"aaa bbb"ccc.tex`
is the file `xxxaaa bbbccc.tex` all spaces between pairs of `"` are preserved, all `"`are removed and not part of the filename.  It is not possible to reference a file with `"` in its name.

Many `babel` languages make `"`active and a shorthand with various constructs such as `"-` being a hyphen that does not suppress further hyphenation

Comment: Ah... I forgot about babel languages. Maybe I will turn the shorthands off. Evidently I need to think about this more than I had andticipated.

Comment: The "german" package uses `"a` as an alias for `\"a` for example, and that is widely used.